# Fieldsets & legends vs sections & headings in .net

Tags: asp.net, html, tags

Is there any real difference between these when used in an aspx web form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have semantic differences. A fieldset is designed to encapsulate a group of fields, inputs or controls. Sections and headings are more designed for actual text content (your actual copy in the literary sense).